# Template specialization with a template

Tags: c++, templates

I would like to define the following function in C++11:

```
// This is the general function that should
// never been instantiated
//
template <typename T>
T load(const std::string& filename) {
  return T{};
}
```

for various types.

I would like to specialize this function for the family of types std::vector< S > (or any templated class). Something like :

```
template <typename std::vector<S>>
std::vector<S> load(const std::string& filename) {
  // Implementation
}
```

This code obviously does not work. But how could I do that?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: you may check the type of T inside the function and decide what to do

Comment: BTW , what is the problem with :          template <typename T>
std::vector<T> load(const std::string& filename) {
  // Implementation
}

Comment: @Human: I have tried and it does not work which is not surprising.

Comment: What you mean by not worked?

Comment: @Human: Does not compile.

Comment: Oh sorry, I am not familiar with templates. I am using c++11 compiler. I do not know if things changed from previous

Comment: @HumamHelfawi: it compiles, problem is to use it (and it is possible to use it, but do you really want to cast it when calling the function like [that](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8ae57c011cfa55d9)) ?

Answer (score 6):

Function cannot be partial specialized, but struct/class can, so forward your implementation to dedicated struct:

```
template <typename T> struct load_helper;

template <typename T> struct load_helper<std::vector<T>>
{
    std::vector<T> operator ()(const std::string& filename) const
    {
        // Your implementation
    }
};

template <typename T>
T load(const std::string& filename) {
  return load_helper<T>{}(filename);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. It seems the best way to do it so far,

Answer (score 2):

In C++ there is no *function template partial specialization*. What you would like to do is to define an *overload* for your function template, like:

```
// warning: this will not work in your case
template<typename S>
std::vector<S> load(const std::string& filename);
```

Though, it will not work in your case, because you can't overload a function changing only its return type.

Comment: OP "can" overload only by return type, but it will have to cast the function to correct type each time...

Comment: @Jarod42 Are you sure? Wouldn't be such an overload ambiguous?

Comment: You can call it that [way](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8ae57c011cfa55d9). But I would avoid that if possible.

Comment: @Jarod42 Wow, pretty awkward :) Is that cast legal? I have to admit I can't understand why it works! And why I have to cast `load<double>` if I want to return a `vector<double>`?

Comment: `load<int>` may be the one which return `int` or `std::vector<int>`, so you have to specify which overload to take.